# Does dpkg-buildpackage offer control over its output?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I could not find no verbosity, quiet, silent, etc flags for dpkg-buildpackage.
For instance, it prints [info] messages I am interested in, but also prints what is going on within all its rules file targets.
I would like to **not output that**.

Is building a debian package profile related ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dpkg-buildpackage` doesn’t control the package build’s output, but Policy-compliant packages can provide [a “terse” mode](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-source.html#s-debianrules-options), controlled by `DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS`:

```
DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS=terse dpkg-buildpackage ...
```

This isn’t guaranteed to make much difference; the results will depend on the build itself (`debian/rules` in the source package). Most Debian packages err on the side of verbosity, because it makes it much easier to fix problems by reading build logs.